# Continuity of functions with multiple variables

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, topological-vector-spaces, product-space

I have started working on topology and there has been a question I can't figure out.

Consider a function $f$ defined on topological spaces $X\times Y$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Both space are finite dimensional. X is endowed with euclidean topology (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $Y$ is endowed with discrete topology (for example a discrete space $\{1,2,3,...,|Y|\}$). $f$ is linear on $X$.

By definition, we know that $f$ is continuous on $X$ as a linear application on a finite dimensional space. We also know that $f$ is continuous on $Y$ as $Y$ is endowed with discrete topology.

Therefore, we know that $f$ is continuous on $X$ and $f$ is continuous on $Y$. In general, I know that if a function is continuous on each variable it is not enough to deduce that $f$ is continuous on the product space of the variables.

However, I can't figure out if the function $f$ defined above is continuous on $X\times Y$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the codomain of $f$?

Comment: The codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. Sorry for forgetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$f^{-1}(O)=\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)\in O\}=\bigcup_{y\in Y}\big\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)\in O\big\}=\bigcup_{y\in Y}\Big(\big\{x\in X\mid f(x,y)\in O\big\}\times\{y\}\Big).$$
Note that you have an open set as the union of open sets on the right side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I am not sure I understood. The union of finite open set is still on the set $Y$ and not on $X\times Y$?

Comment: No, it is an infinite union. The point is that $Y$ having the discrete topology means that you can turn each open "section" $\{f(x,y)\in O\mid x\in X\}$ for a given $y$ in an open rectangle $\{f(x,y)\in O\mid x\in X\}\times\{y\}$. Such open rectangles are open in the product topology and an arbitrary union of open sets is open in every topological space.